# Aggravating IPhone problem, apps when downloaded on one phone go to all phones

Tags: applications

When I download an app on my iPhone, it is automatically downloaded to my parents iPhones. It is extremely aggravating when my little sister shows me her iPod with all my games. How do I stop this? Everything with iCloud is off.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your sister's iPod /parent's iPhones.

1. Go to Settings -> Stores
2. Disable Automatic Downloads

Comment: Beat you by 21 seconds! :-P

Comment: You are 12 seconds faster!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have [automatic downloads on.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4539) Go to Settings>Store on your iPhone. Sign in, if you aren't already. Then you should be able to turn on (or off) automatic downloads):
[image]
I believe you'll have to do the same for your sister's iPod as well, though I'm not completely sure, as we don't have multiple iOS devices.